# Which SMT-LIB attributes does Z3 support, and why?

Tags: z3

The SMT-LIB standard enables arbitrary attributes, but prescribes only very few, e.g. `:pattern`. Z3, on the other hand, currently only supports a few selected attributes, and issues a warning for unrecognised ones.

Which attributes are supported, and what is their typical use case?

Answer (score 1):

#### Attributes

- `:named`: named terms can be included in unsat cores
- `:weight`: heavier quantifiers make Z3 reach its quantifier instantiation depth threshold more quickly
- `:qid`: identify quantifiers, e.g. when obtaining instantiation statistics
- `:pattern`: syntactic hints for when to instantiate a quantifier in e-matching
- `:no-pattern`: prevent Z3 from using certain terms when inferring patterns
- `:ex-act`: seems like dead code, to be removed
- `:skolemid`: specific to [VCC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/vcc-a-verifier-for-concurrent-c/)/[Boogie](https://github.com/boogie-org/boogie/) use
- `:lblneg`, `:lblpos`: associated with Boogie labels to track the source of counter-examples

#### Notes

- Information partly provided by Z3's very own Nikolaj Bjorner, see also [Z3 issue #4536](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/4536).
- See also Z3 source file [smt2parser.cpp](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/parsers/smt2/smt2parser.cpp)